# why is b:changedtick never zero?

Tags: variables

As the Title states `b:changedtick` is never zero.
No plugin or special setting seems to be involved.

Even :

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE
:echo b:changedtick
```

returns a value != 0

The same happens if I start vim with a filename (no matter if the file exists)

Comment: Seems like a side-effect of the implementation, see e.g. `unchanged()` and `changed()` in `misc1.c`.

Comment: I see. The file is named misc1 here. I guess `b:changedtick` does not reliantly reflect the number of changes